# Show InfoWindow marker contain data from database

Tags: javascript, google-maps-markers

I have marker that places in each position from lat lng from database, now I want to show in InfoWindow of marker when it's clicked show each data row from it's own marker thats have information based on lat lng from database. This is my code:

```
//menampilkan INFOWINDOW MARKER A

        var isi =
        "<b>Jumlah Kejadian</b> = 10 <br> <b>Kendaraan yang terlibat</b> = 10"
        ;

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
          content: isi
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(homeMarker, 'click', function() {
          infowindow.open(map,homeMarker);
        });

//menampilkan INFOWINDOW MARKER B
        var isi2 = 
        "<b>Jumlah Kejadian</b> = 1 <br> <b>Kendaraan yang terlibat</b> = 2"
        // '<IMG BORDER="1" ALIGN="center" SRC="rambulucu.jpg">'

        var infowindow2 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
          content: isi2
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(homeMarker2, 'click', function() {
          infowindow2.open(map,homeMarker2);
        });      
  }
});
```

That marker only contain information from my own info, not from database. This is my database :

[image: I want to show like "Nama, Jumlah kejadian, etc" to show on marker that clicked only contain its own data]

I want to show like "Nama, Jumlah kejadian, etc" to show on marker that clicked only contain its own data

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>    
function initialize() {

                          // you can pass your php variable to javascript variable(locations) as an array.
                            var locations = [
                            ['Lorem Ipsum Dolor sit amet 1', 1.1031994976981054,104.07207012176514, 3],
                            ['Lorem Ipsum Dolor sit amet 2', 1.1041994976981054,104.07307012176514, 2],
                            ['Lorem Ipsum Dolor sit amet 3', 1.1021994976981054,104.07407012176514, 1]
                                                ];

                                var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(locations[0][1], locations[0][2]);
                                var mapOptions = {
                                    zoom: 15,
                                    center: myLatlng
                                };



                                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
                                var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

                                var marker, i;
                                // you can use looping to show multiple marker.
                                    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
                                      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
                                        map: map
                                      });

                                      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
                                        return function() {
                                          infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
                                          infowindow.open(map, marker);
                                        }
                                      })(marker, i));
                                    }



                                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
                                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                                });

                                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function (e) {
                                    document.getElementById("Latitude").value = e.latLng.lat();
                                    document.getElementById("Longitude").value = e.latLng.lng();
                                });
                        }

                        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>

<style>
 #map-canvas{
   width: 500px;
   border: 1px solid red;
   height: 500px;
 }
</style>

<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

Comment: it's still won't show the information, would you please give the detail code of <?php echo... until end ?
And what's the meaning of "maxWidth" ?